# Is a battery always electrically neutral in the circuit? If so, why?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, batteries

[image]

In this circuit, the sum of the charges on both the plates is 0.The sum of the charges present on the negative terminal and positive terminal of the battery is also 0 (I think). Is it possible for the sum of the charges on the 2 terminals of the battery to not be 0, so that the net charge on the two plates is also not 0?

Comment: It's not clear if you are talking about the battery or the capacitor.

Comment: @BobD I am talking about the battery.

Comment: Then why do you say ignore the word dielectric when it has nothing to do with the battery?

Comment: @BobD I have corrected it.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible for the sum of the charges on the 2 terminals of the battery to not be 0, so that the net charge on the two plates is also not 0?

It is possible, but that would violate one of the three assumptions of circuit theory. The assumptions of circuit theory are as follows (see Nilsson and Riedel, Electric Circuits, ch 1):

1. there is no net charge on any circuit element
2. there is no magnetic coupling between circuit elements
3. the circuit is small compared to the speed of light and the time scales of interest

So assumption 1) would be violated. That would mean that you would not be able to treat the circuit using circuit theory, but would require Maxwell's equations instead. Or at least the electroquasistatic approximation to Maxwell's equations.

Comment: How often does the first assumption hold true in real life?

Comment: @Pumpkin_Star It's never true. It's often an adequate approximation. See my answer.

Comment: @Pumpkin_Star usually we don't ask whether an assumption is "true" or not. As John Doty says any assumption is almost trivially never "true". Instead we ask if an assumption is "valid". This means that using the assumption leads to predictions that are within the accuracy of our measurements. In those senses the first assumption is never "true", but it is very often "valid".

Comment: Thank you. So it is very unlikely for the battery to have a significant amount of net charge. Is there some physical reason behind this? I am not very interested in trivial cases. Yes, maybe on some condition, the battery develops a minor charge. I am not much bothered about it. I am mainly asking why exactly can the battery not have any substantial or significant amount of net charge?

Comment: @Pumpkin_Star basically it is because electrostatic forces are very strong. So if there were any significant net charge on an object then it would quickly pull charges towards itself until the charges were more or less neutralized.

Comment: Oh, so does that mean that the battery will not be able to acquire any charge because every electron that enters the battery through the positive terminal must be pushed to the negative because of the field of the battery?  And this is slightly off-topic, but do the terminals of the battery have equal and opposite charge on their terminals even when the battery is not connected to anything?

Comment: @Pumpkin_Star asked “every electron that enters the battery through the positive terminal must be pushed to the negative”. It is a bit more complicated than that. There are chemical reactions at each electrode that bind or release electrons and produce ions or metal. And then in the electrolyte there is a current of both positive and negative ions. But simplifying substantially, yes, what you say is the essence of what happens.

Comment: It is easy to give a static charge to an electric circuit. However, the static charge mostly does not affect the circuit's functioning, so we can analyze them independently. Unless you introduce it suddenly, in which case we call it an ESD event (electrostatic discharge) which can damage some types of components that are especially delicate.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: How should I interpret assumption 1? It looks to me like there are net charges on both of the wires leading from the battery to the capacitor, one a positive and one a negative charge. So any interesting circuit would violate assumption 1. Or is it meant to say that the circuit as a whole has no net charge?

Comment: @JanKanis circuit analysis is based on a "lumped element" model. Each lumped element has no net charge in the model. So the capacitor has no net charge because the positive and negative plates are both part of the same lumped element.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the capacitance internal to it, your capacitor has external capacitance to surrounding objects and the rest of the universe. Any net charge on the capacitor produces a potential between the capacitor and these objects.

When analyzing circuits, we often ignore this "stray" capacitance, since it is  small. Especially in textbooks: never trust textbook idealizations to capture all of the relevant physics. The capacitor is just assumed to have whatever potential it's predicted to have, ignoring the stray capacitance. Since the stray capacitance is small, only a small amount of charge is needed to make this happen, small enough to often be ignored.

Comment: My main doubt is related to battery. I am confused about how this external capacitance is affecting the battery.

Comment: @Pumpkin_Star Well, the battery may have some charge on it, and therefore have a potential relative to its surroundings. Just like you do when you rub your shoes on carpet on a dry day. Does that affect you? The quantity is small, nanocoulombs. Compare to the kilocoulombs common batteries can deliver as current.

Comment: And the reason behind the quantity being small is?

Comment: Batteries and capacitors push electrons out one terminal and push them in the other. Having extra electrons would not change this.

Comment: @mmesser314 Yes. But why is it not possible for the battery to retain some of the electrons and get a negative charge on it? or conversely, let more than a usual number of electrons into the conducting wire and hence gain a positive charge?

Comment: @Pumpkin_Star Consider the consequences if it were to do so. The capacitance of a battery you can hold in your hand to the environment is about 10 pF. Now imagine that the battery pushes out an ampere of electrons for one second, thus gaining a coulomb of charge. The resulting electrostatic potential would be (1 C)/(10 pF), or 100 billion volts. The battery can't produce that kind of potential, so it has to stay very close to perfectly neutral.

Comment: Thank you very much! So, it is because the capacitance of the battery is very low.  And is it that the battery must have very low capacitance for it to work as a battery? As in if the capacitance increases, then the battery might not take in and push out the electrons from and to the wires, so it would be a bad battery? Or is it just because the types of batteries that are available and we use have low capacitance?

Comment: The vacuum permittivity $\epsilon_0$ relates the capacitance of an object to its dimensions. It's a very small number, ~9 pF/m. So, simple objects of human scale (like batteries) have external capacitances in pF.

Comment: Ok, so what I have understood is that the reason is 1. because of the battery's field which Dale mentions, and because of the battery having low capacitance which you mention. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Pumpkin_Star In layman's terms: Electric charges really really really really want to stay neutral. Any reasonable amount of pushing force (voltage) only manages to create a small imbalance from neutral.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption that a battery is neutral is usually valid if we look at the effects of the amount of charge that would be involved.

Let's say we have a battery with 1 Ah capacity. For comparison, a vehicle battery may store 40 Ah, an LR6 battery or 18650 LiPo around 2 Ah. This 1 Ah battery will store 3600 C, 3.6 kC of charge, 1 amp flowing for 3600 seconds, in operation as a battery.

The battery may have a typical capacitance to ground of 100 pF. Once an object is charged to 10 kV, it will begin to discharge itself with corona, or across damp surfaces, so we'll set that as the target. A 100 pF capacitor charged to 10 kV stores CV = 1 µC. The unbalanced charge to ground is a totally negligible fraction of the operating charge as a battery.

Bear in mind that this charge on the battery with respect to ground merely raises the potential of the battery and the circuit it's connected to. It does not affect the differential voltage that the battery supplies to the circuit.

Until ... If that 10 kV discharges to ground, and the current flows through a part of the circuit of any significant length, the rapid change of current through the inductance of the part of the circuit could cause a large voltage across that part. This could disrupt operation or even damage the circuit. One of the tests that finished packaged products are often subjected to is being hit with such a discharge, to make sure the resulting currents flow in safe areas of the product.